# JQuery Dialog display in firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-dialog

I sometimes have a problem with the display of a regular JQuery Dialog box. My code goes something like this:

```
<div  id="instructor-dialog" title="Instructor Dialog" style="display:none;">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Instructor Information :</legend>
    <div id="instructorMessages" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div id="instructorContainer"></div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

And initialization:

```
function loadInstructorDialog(id) {
  $(function () {
    $("#instructor-dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: getDialogHeight(700),
        width: getDialogWidth(700),
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Close Window": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        open: function () {
            $('#instructorMessages').empty();
            $('#instructorMessages').hide();
            ajLoadInstructorAddEditForm(id, 'instructorContainer', 'instructorMessages');
        },
        close: function () {
            $('#instructorContainer').empty();
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    });
  });
  $("#instructor-dialog").dialog("open");
}
```

The problem is that when i invoke the function `loadInstructorDialog` sometimes the dialog shows up ok and sometimes not. Usually the first couple of times it gets displayed and then in the 3rd or 4th time it is not. When it is not displayed nothing else can be clicked on the page (it seems that the dialogs open but is not displayed - when i mouse over the place that the dialog box title should have been i get the usual move - resize cursor that indicates that the dialog is open but is not displayed ). When i resize manually the firefox window the dialog gets displayed (the dialog also gets displayed when I switch browser tabs). No problems displayed in Console...(so weird...).

Has anyone else had this problem?

Oh btw the same code seems to be working fine in Chrome.

If anyone can shed some light....

Comment: Any particular reason why `$("#instructor-dialog").dialog("open");` is outside of the scope of the ready function `$(function() {})`?

Comment: Your code is working perfect on Firefox version 34.0.5, http://jsfiddle.net/srupali/03to46gn/1/ . Try to upgrade browser and if you're still facing the same problem then might be there could be some issue with other piece of code.

Comment: @dbf thats used to call the `open` for dialog... is there anything wrong doing so?

Comment: my browswer version is the latest... 34.0.5

Comment: So are you facing the same problem with this fiddle as well?

Comment: @MaVRoSCy Nothing is ever wrong until something does not work as expected ;)

Comment: @s-rupali the fiddle works just fine for me....

Comment: Okay, as you can see in the fiddle i have commented 3 function `getDialogHeight`, `getDialogWidth`, and `ajLoadInstructorAddEditForm`, so there could be something wrong with one of these three. Better if you can post these functions' definition as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the initialization of the dialog out of the `loadInstructorDialog(id)` function.

```
function loadInstructorDialog(id) {  
  $("#instructor-dialog").dialog("open");
}

$(function () {
    $("#instructor-dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: getDialogHeight(700),
        width: getDialogWidth(700),
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Close Window": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        open: function () {
            $('#instructorMessages').empty();
            $('#instructorMessages').hide();
            ajLoadInstructorAddEditForm(id, 'instructorContainer', 'instructorMessages');
        },
        close: function () {
            $('#instructorContainer').empty();
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    });
  });
```